# Beginning elisp How to write division without actually using division sign

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I am starting elisp, I want to write a function to divide 2 numbers without using the divison sign. I get the error Symbol's value as variable is void: div

```
(cl-flet ((div (x y z)
            (cond ((< x y) (message "hello world"))
                  ((> x y) (div (- x y) y (+ 1 z))))))
  (let ((a 30) (b 10))
    (div a b 1)))
```

The same function I have written in erlang:

```
start(A, B)->
    ds(A, B, 0).

ds(A, B, C) when ( A -  ( B * (C + 1))) >=  0 ->
    ds(A, B, C+1);
ds(_A, _B, C) ->
 C.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `flet` for recursive functions, you have to use `labels` instead.

Comment: Indeed, tho he used `cl-flet` so he should replace it with `cl-labels`.

Comment: @Stefan Indeed, though I was hoping that that would be obvious. :-D

Comment: You're probably right, but given that cl.el's had an `flet` which was different from `cl-flet` (this last one being like CommonLisp's `flet`) and which did allow recursive definitions, I thought it was worth pointing out the obvious ;-)